# date format of textfield using java script and php

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am making a form that has a date field using textfield, i want my date field to have a label format inside the textfield, here's the picture:
 [image] 
 after clicking on the textfield the format will be erased and the hyphen will remain like this picture:
 [image]
 i already made the code for the label format,
here's my code:

```
<input type="text" name="date" value="DD_MM_YYYY" id="date" style="width:180px" onclick="if(this.value=='DD_MM_YYYY'){this.value=''}"  />
</p>
```

My problem now is the hypen that will remain after clicking the textfield.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, I'd suggest using a mask plugin for your use-case, even though I'd personally prefer a datepicker one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Masked Input Plugin.
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

You can define your own type of mask by using the code:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#myinput").mask("99-99-9999",{placeholder:" "});
});
```

Then you can define a placeholder to the input:

```
<input id='myinput' placeholder='dd-mm-yyyy'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the placeholder attribute.

```
<input placeholder="  -  -    " value="DD-MM-YYYY" />
```

You can continue to set the value to nothing when the element is focused. On blur set the value back to `DD-MM-YYYY`.

Note that this attribute isn't supported by all browsers.